# How can "round" return a float?

Tags: php

PHP float type is IEEE-754 binary64.

The number 59.95 cannot be stored precisely in binary. In IEEE-754 binary64 the representation of `59.95` should be `59.9500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125`.

However, when I do

```
<?php 

return 59.95
```

It returns 59.95. How is that possible?

Also the function [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) claims to return  the rounded value of val to specified precision as a float. But how is this possible? There exists no float representation of `59.95` with only two two digits after the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP controls the floating point to string precision through the `precision` ini setting. This value is `14` by default.

If you instead use `32` or some other arbitrarily larger value, you'll see what you're looking for:

```
> php -d "precision=32" -r "print(59.95);"
59.950000000000002842170943040401
                ^-- Default precision stops here
```

Since the divergence from the "exact" value happens after the default precision value, the value is printed as what you probably expected:

```
> php -d "precision=14" -r "print(59.95);"
59.95
```

Comment: This makes sense. Also round(59.59, 2) returns 59.590000000000003410605131648480892181396484375 now. Thanks!

Comment: It's important to remember that it's the same value returned in both cases; it's just printed differently when you change `precision`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer:

When debugging, it is sometimes desirable not to output with standard precision. This can be done very easily with printf (and sprintf etc) with the number of digits you want:

```
<?php
$float = 59.59;
printf("%0.30e",$float);
//5.959000000000000341060513164848e+1
```

[Try it self.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e878b792ee53822330873d8616a6a15b7a2e6951)